# Error building haskell llvm bindings on Linux

Tags: haskell, llvm, llvm-3.0

I built llvm 3.0, downloaded from [here](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#3.0). I did:

> ./configure CC=gcc CXX=g++ --enable-shared
>
> sudo make -j5 -s install

Next, I cloned the LLVM bindings from [here](https://github.com/bos/llvm). I am trying:

> runhaskell Setup configure

But I get:

> Configuring llvm-3.0.0.0...
>
> Setup.lhs: At least the following dependencies are missing:
>
> llvm-base ==3.0.*, type-level -any

I am running Linux Mint 64-bit (equivalent to Ubuntu 11.0). GHC is 6.12.3. I tried a cabal install but apparently the llvm version is too old to run some examples (am I mistaken?).

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bryan recently split the `llvm` package in two, that split has not yet made it to hackage. So if you don't want to simply cabal install the hackage version,

1. install the `type-level` package (cabal install should work fine)
2. cd into the `base` subdirectory of the llvm-repo, install `llvm-base`
3. cd into the `llvm` directory, install

I have not tried it, so it might not work, but usually Bryan's repos are buildable, so there's a good chance that it does.

Comment: I am not sure if it's appropriate to post a follow-up here. But I'll do. I tried building llvm-base and I got a compilation error requiring the macro __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS to be defined before including DataTypes. Even if I add -D option manually to gcc (by redefining gcc as a bash script.. I know it's horrible), I get "Could not find module `LLVM.Target.TARGET':" in LLVM/Target/Native.hs:8:7.

Comment: `TARGET` is a macro specifying the architecture. That must be defined somewhere to choose the correct module, a quick look didn't reveal where exactly. I doubt it would work with adding `-DTARGET=X86` (for example) to the `-cpp-options` in the .cabal file. It's probably best to just install the latest hackage version.

Comment: I did try that.. It gives a bunch of link errors when I try to compile any of the examples.

Comment: Not surprising. After a look in `configure.ac`, you might have a better chance with `export target=YOUR_PLATFORM` before installing, but I'm not too optimistic. Why don't you just install the hackage version?

Comment: No I meant I tried installing the hackage version (not I tried the options). It fails to compile the examples.. Maybe I am doing something wrong.. A lot of linking errors!

Comment: Ah, current version is compatible with llvm 2.9 and 2.8, probably it's incompatible with 3.0. Have you tried simply `cabal install` inside `llvm/base` (and then `llvm`)? According to `INSTALL.md` that should likely work if llvm is in a standard place. But that again doesn't speak of 3.0 yet. You could try the mailing list - haskell-llvm@projects.haskellorg - for expert help.

Comment: So I removed llvm-3.0 and installed llvm-2.8. I ran cabal install from inside base.. I am getting some type error. Thanks for the great help so far :) but I quit!